# Мониторинг логов Zabbix'ом

Tags: логирование, zabbix, мониторинг

Имею записи в лог файле:

> 2018-07-04 09:45:53.867 [error] [ddb3a5f3-bb55-45df-8610-afcdb1f409e6][10708937][10708937]<0.31891.68>@riak_manager:error_hook_call:303 Riak manager Error: {error,timeout_get_worker}
> ErrorCode: <<"RIKMNG0005">>

Номер ошибки может меняться, например: RIKMNG0002, RIKMNG0007, RIKMNG0011.

**Создал элемент данных:**

**Имя** rikmng

**Тип** Zabbix агент (активный)

**Ключ** rikmng["/DATA/logs/app1/error.log","ErrorCode: <<"RIKMNG([0-9]+)">>",,,,]

**Тип информации** Журнал (лог)

В узле сети напротив этого элемента данных пишет: **Unsupported item key**.

В логах zabbix агента

> 22836:20180704:132224.970 active check "rikmng["/DATA/logs/app1/error.log","ErrorCode: <<"RIKMNG([0-9]+)">>",,,,]" is not supported

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему элемент данных не поддерживается? Где я накосячил?
2. Если я правильно понял документацию, то в ответ будут приходить только цифры ия могу настроить тригер на совпадение с жтими цифрами, правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, правильно так

**Ключ** log["/DATA/logs/app1/error.log","ErrorCode: <<"RIKMNG([0-9]+)">>",,,,]